# CS0436 compiler warning with a shared project

Tags: c#, .net, dependencies, compiler-warnings, shared-project

We have two solutions (**C#, VS2015**) that consist of a few projects.
The Basic-Solution with namespace **Wpf** has some classes that are re-written in the More Advanced - Solution in the namespace **Wpf.Advanced** because the more advanced solution uses different data types for example.

Since every code-change in one of the classes, that are present in both solutions, needs to be rewritten in the second file, we decided to change the structure and use a **shared project** as a single place where the files should be located for both solutions.

We now use "usings" in combination with precompiler **#if #else #endif** blocks to merge the two files into one by changing the data types based on the project (via a compilation symbol **ADVANCED**).

Now to the problem:

Since some of our example projects need to reference both, the **Wpf** and the shared project we get the mentioned warnings **CS0436** because some objects, that now exist in the shared project and in the namespace **Wpf**.

How can I resolve this issue?
I mean, everything works, but no warning is better than any warning, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I just had similar situation. In exe project I referenced dll and shared project. The dll in turn was referencing shared project. The solution was to exclude the shared project from the exe project. Since the shared project gets referenced from the dll the exe gets all of them too.
It may look trivial unless you are not experienced with shared projects.

Answer (score 0):

The namespace `NamespaceName1` in `NamespaceName2` conflicts with the type `TypeName1` in `NamespaceName3`

This error occurs when the imported type and the imported namespace have the same fully qualified name. When that duplicate name is referenced, the compiler is unable to distinguish between the two.